# Flask-SQLAlchemy query with negative condition on filter

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make an [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/index.html) query with a negative condition on method `filter_by()`.

I can easily get who is admin on my system with `User.query.filter_by(admin=True)` and who isn't with `User.query.filter_by(admin=False)` but I want to make a query with a filter that says what to ignore, for example:

```
notRach = User.query.filter_by(name!='Rachmaninoff')
# queries for all users whose name isn't Rachmaninoff
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter_by()` takes keyword arguments, so you are required to pass in the fields with `=`, whereas [`filter()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter) will allow you use `!=`, e.g.

```
User.query.filter(User.name != 'Rachmaninoff')
```

Notice `filter()` and `User.name` in the `filter()` argument